# Do i use PHP while loop or SQL group_concat

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Both codes does the same Job, But which one is better to use and when to use?

### ***PHP method***

```
$names = [];
$Query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM names";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($Query);
$stmt->execute();
while ($name = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $names[] = $name['epic'];
}
$names = implode(',', $names);
```

---

### ***SQL method***

```
$Query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name) AS names FROM names";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($Query);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$names = $row['names'];
```

Comment: are you looking for this response :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700623/pdos-query-vs-execute

Comment: Usually you should do as much as possible inside sql, as the dbms is optimized to do this kind of operations

Comment: @MOHAMMEDYASSINEChabli nope, that totally a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. `GROUP_CONCAT()` has the limit which is imposed by `group_concat_max_len` system option, and its length is 1024 by default ([more info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)).

Also, it will concatenate non-null values, which you may want to handle in a different way, rather than just ignoring them.

Comment: As i read, I can increase this `group_concat_max_len` as i want, But in case i set the limit to `999999`, Wouldn't that have some effect on the Database?

Comment: @Toleo well, it's also constrained by `max_allowed_packet`, which _could_ have an effect. See here for more:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5019936/197487
https://reformatcode.com/code/mysql/is-increasing-groupconcatmaxlen-to-500000-will-cause-a-performance-issue

Comment: In case i needed to increase `group_concat_max_len` to `200,000`, Which method would you recommend? the `SQL` or `PHP`?

Comment: @Toleo never ask an imaginary question

Comment: @YourCommonSense, tbh, i don't get where is the imaginary part in my question,Is it the increasing to `200,000`? If yes, then i should use `PHP` method to be more future proof, Or is it bad if i set it globally and better if i set `200,000` per session only?

Comment: @Toleo okay, what would be the use of the 200,000 comma separated names then?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I want a full serialized `Id` list, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ....] to 50,000 `id` at a single variable, it would require `200,000` at least.

Comment: @Toleo 1. ugly comma-separation is anything but serialization. 2. 50,000 id will make 50,000 elements not 200,000. 3. You failed to answer the question **what would be the use of the 200,000 comma separated names**, or 50,000 ids.

Comment: @YourCommonSense 1.Select all distincted `id`s or `names`. 2. Put it inside `array()`. 3. Make it as Autocomplete list for Search Input.

Comment: @Toleo WAT? Autocomplete consists of 200,000 entries? It will make megabytes to send! Just as usual, a weird request reveals lack of knowledge, you should learn what autocomplete is and how it is implemented.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I understand it would be a heavy dictionary search, And that i can just use AJAX to get the data part by part, But still want to make it as an experiment, But i still wonder if `50,000` `group_concat` is worth it or PHP is better for this job.

Comment: @Toleo it makes absolutely no sense to create a string consists of 50,000 comma separated values in the first place. The sooner you'll understand this the less time you'll waste. DO you really think that a user would scroll down 50,000 suggestions? What are you thinking about?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Nope, Not the User, But me, As i said, I use it as an experiment to check why is it bad, how much does a `50,000` word is worth on the `RAM` and `CPU` to be read, Just static for me to understand the limits of something.

Comment: So, your question is indeed an imaginery one, not a real question. So, it is kinda pointless. With a few records, you will not see significant difference between the two approaches. If you have lots of records to be conactenated, then you probably have a design problem. But if you are so curious, then just simply test it yourself.